# Why is 24 lines a common default terminal height?

Tags: coding-standards, history

80x24 characters seems to be a very common default for terminal windows.  This [answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/148678/9742) provides a very good historical reason as to why the width is 80 characters.

But why is the height commonly 24 (or 25) lines?

Comment: Save your history questions for next week :P. Too late now though: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/3546/programmers-se-contest-the-complete-outline

Comment: 80×25 is actually more common

Comment: @vartec : Edited the question for either 24 or 25 lines.

Comment: I don't know about 25 lines, but whenever I open PuTTY it defaults to 80x24.

Comment: Probably partly because 80x25 is just under 2K.  Makes it easy to have a 2K screen buffer.

Comment: @StevenBurnap Isn't 80X25 exactly 2000?

Comment: Yes.  And 80x26 is 2080, which is bigger than 2K.  Having a 2K+32byte buffer would be awkward, more awkward than having 24 bytes in the buffer that aren't used.

Comment: @KrisHarper: I think the VT100 was 24 lines plus a status line, though some other display devices are 24 lines without any status indicator.  From a hardware perspective, counting display addresses linearly is a little harder than adding eight bytes of padding every three rows, but the latter approach leaves 64 bytes scattered throughout memory.

Comment: The width is 80 because the original punch cards (1 line of code) were 80.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Early terminals were built around the same cathode ray tubes that were used for televisions. In the 1960's and 1970's these were all 4:3 aspect ratio.

If the display [needs to fit 80 characters across the width](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/148677/why-is-80-characters-the-standard-limit-for-code-width) then given the aspect ratio of the standard characters which was taller than 3:4 (if I remember correctly) and allowing for a larger space between lines than between characters you get to fit 24 or 25 lines on the display.

*I haven't done the exact maths because I can't remember (or find) the exact character aspect ratio or line spacing.*

Comment: That depends on the bitmap used for the characters.  I cannot find an image of the physical screen to see.  Also note that  132 character widths were available.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen - I'm having problems finding exact numbers too. If I remember correctly the aspect ratio of the characters used for the 132 character displays were different - thinner than the standard 80 character displays.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen If it helps, I've got an 80x25 ASCII terminal from IBM, of which the 25th line is a status line. I had brightness turned down when I took it but if it helps, here's a photo. http://i.imgur.com/bU2Hd1X.jpg

Answer (score 9):

The height of the vt100 terminal.

Emulators get the best vt100 compatability at that size.

Comment: If so, why did a vt100 display 24 lines?

Comment: Most likely a memory issue.  They may have had 1 KB of memory and needed more than 24 bytes for variables.

Comment: I cannot count.  _2_ KB.